# AFrame issue with crossorigin object model showing up but not the texture

Tags: collada, object-model, aframe

I'm having a problem with my obj models. I've set crossorigin="anonymous" for both my obj and mtl file. The model shows up perfectly if the obj/mtl/jpg are from my computer. however when i put these files on AWS s3 and change the permissions, it's telling me "DOMException: failed to execute 'textImage2D' on webRenderingContext': the cross-origin image at ........
i don't run into this problem with collada models just object models.

Answer (score 1):

Check the paths in the MTL are all correct and point to the textures hosted in the right place.

Make sure that you have CORS-enabled on wherever you are serving your assets.

Comment: Make sure CORS is also enabled on your S3 bucket.